# Mysql: count and group unique emails in associated tables by polymorphic join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The relevant part of my schema (Mysql 5.6.24) is thus:

```
table: training_event_invitees
    registered (tinyint)
    invitee_id (id)
    invitee_type (varchar)

table: users
    id (integer)
    email (varchar)
    school_id (integer)

table: contacts
    id (integer)
    email (varchar)
    school_id (integer)

table: schools
    id (integer)
    email (varchar)
```

I want to try to do the following:  get all the training_event_invitees that have registered set to 1, get the associated school, user and contact records, and then group them by school_id, and return the school id and the count of unique email addresses from that school.

training_event_invitees has a two-column foreign key, using invitee_id and invitee_type:  invitee_type would be either "School", "User" or "Contact", and references the id field from the corresponding table.

So, algorithmically, it's something like

```
- get all the registered training_event_invitees
- get all of the associated user, contact and school records
- group these by users.school_id, contacts.school_id or schools.id
- count the number of distinct emails in each group
```

So, it should return an array like
    [
      [1234, 6],
      [3407, 2]
    ]

where 1234 and 3407 are values of school_id and 6 and 2 are the count of distinct emails.

I can break this down into a few steps, but there must be a one-hit way to do it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Give sample output you desire and a script to generate all the SQL structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to combine the two tables using `left join`, and then doing the aggregation:

```
select coalesce(u.school_id, c.school_id) as school_id,
       count(distinct coalesce(u.email, c.email)) as num_emails
from training_event_invitees tei left join
     users u
     on u.id = tei.invitee_id and tei.invitee_type = 'user' left join
     contacts c
     on c.id = tei.invitee_id and tei.invitee_type = 'contact'
where tei.registered = 1
group by coalesce(u.school_id, c.school_id);
```

EDIT:

To include the school, follow the same logic:

```
select coalesce(u.school_id, c.school_id, s.id) as school_id,
       count(distinct coalesce(u.email, c.email, s.email)) as num_emails
from training_event_invitees tei left join
     users u
     on u.id = tei.invitee_id and tei.invitee_type = 'user' left join
     contacts c
     on c.id = tei.invitee_id and tei.invitee_type = 'contact' left join
     schools s
     on s.id = tei.invitee_id and tei.invitee_type = 'school'
where tei.registered = 1
group by coalesce(u.school_id, c.school_id, s.id);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think this isn't quite getting the right results:  I did it using a slower, less clever method, and my method returned 15 extra rows (2895 rows vs 2880 from yours, so it's pretty close, relatively speaking).  In each of those cases, there was only one thing in each group, and it was a school (rather than a user or contact).  So is there maybe a bug in your suggestion which doesn't return if there are no users or contacts in the group?

Comment: @MaxWilliams . . . This will only return schools which have at least one invitee.

Comment: But the school itself can be an invitee.  ie some training_event_invitee records could have "invitee_type = 'School', invitee_id = 1234", meaning that the school itself has been invited.  In this instance the email field of the school should be counted.  thanks!  max

Comment: Thanks Gordon - that works perfectly, with one minor correction:  `s.school_id` should be changed to `s.id` in both instances where it occurs.  If you make that edit i'll mark this as correct, thanks.